Would a question about human/social behavior be on-topic
I'd like to ask some questions about the behavior of one of my acquaintances (first I'd like to describe how he treats his friends/relatives under certain circumstances, how he reacts to specific events or topics; then I'd like to get some insights where his behavior might have come from/how one develops such habits/emotional reactions in general; finally, would like to seek some advice how to handle this kind of behavior).
Would such a question be appropriate for the Psychology & Neuroscience forum? I scrolled over all the communities of Stack Exchange, but haven't seen a closer fit yet.

Thank you for asking prior to posting a question. Have a look at the site tour; it provides the necessary information:

Don't ask about...

"Self Help" questions which are personal in nature, seeking medical or professional advice


The answer is thus, "no". Your question would have been closed as "self-help. You can find more information why here: Why was my self-help question closed as off-topic?.
P.s. note that a question about human/social behavior is certainly on topic. Just don't frame it as a self-help question, and link it back to some related prior research.
